# Determining if database is normalized

Tags: database-normalization

In order for a database to be considered as 3rd normal form, should related tables with equal row counts be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

A relation is in 3NF if and only if

- it's in second normal form, and
- every non-prime attribute is non-transitively dependent on every candidate key.

"And related tables have an unequal number of rows" isn't in there.